# VS Code, copyright symbol © shown as � and saved as ï¿½ or �

Tags: visual-studio-code, html-entities, html-encode

In my html source code I have some special symbols like the copyright one `<meta content="© Copyright... />`

For some text editors these are shown correctly as above, but on VS Code I see it as � and after I save the file, the symbol will be shown as ï¿½ and � on other editors.

If I explicitly paste the © on VS Code and save it, then on another text editor it will be saved as Â©.

How can I solve this? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your file's encoding is set to something which can accurately display the symbol (like UTF-8):

[image: Encoding Button in VSCode]

This can be found in the bottom right of the program in the status bar.

See their documentation on [File Encoding Support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_file-encoding-support).

Comment: is there a way to make it global for all the files that I open?

Comment: @BarbuBarbu yes, if you open your editor preferences (File -> Preferences -> User Settings) you can add `"files.encoding": "utf8"`.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here - solved by setting `"files.encoding": "windows1252"` for this workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that the files were saved in ISO-8859-1 encoding, that caused to see like that the symbols even If I had UTF8 set as my default.

Answer (score 0):

Try use HTML codes for special symbols: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: I'm not the only one that works on the file(s) so I can't tell him to use that because he does not have this problem with its editor...